# Asymmetric random walk on the line with barriers

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

The most commonly considered random walk on the line takes one step left or right with equal probability until a barrier is reached (if there are any barriers).

More generally, suppose we fix any probability distribution on the integers with compact support, and consider the random walk that begins at 0 and, at each step, takes an independent random draw from this probability distribution, and moves by that amount.  (The random walk in the previous paragraph corresponds to the probability distribution $P(1)=1/2$ and $P(-1)=1/2$.)   Suppose also that there is a positive integer $n$ such that there are absorbing barriers at $+m$ and at $-m$ whenever $m\ge n$.  Obviously, if the probability distribution is symmetric about 0 then the random walk is equally likely to terminate at a "positive" barrier as at a "negative" barrier.

> Does there exist an *asymmetric* probability distribution such that, for *all sufficiently large $n$*, the associated random walk is equally likely to terminate at a positive barrier as at a negative barrier?

Comment: It looks like the $n$ in the set-up is not the same as the $n$ ($N$?) in the question, right? i.e. the range of the displacements are in $[-n,n]$, but the barriers are at $\pm N$

Comment: Maybe it would have been clearer to use different symbols, but yes, I'm asking about a fixed probability distribution that has compact support, and letting the barriers go to infinity.

Comment: Could you edit the question so the $n$-s are replaced with the $N$-s in the right places?

Comment: O.K., I edited the description.

Comment: Would $P(-2)=1/3$, $P(1)=2/3$ be an asymmetric probability distribution?  Or by asymmetry do you mean a distribution where the *expected* amount of movement on the first step is (say) to the right?

Comment: @Pace: From the sentence that begins "Obviously", I think it's reasonably clear the OP means symmetric in the sense that the distribution of $X_k-X_{k-1}$ is the same as the distribution of $-(X_k-X_{k-1})$.

Comment: Trivial comment: From the optional stopping theorem, if the expected one-step displacement is 0, then *asymptotically* the probability of ending at each barrier is 1/2.

Comment: It looks to me that you have a one parameter family of random walks, one random walk for every  natural number $n$. The random walk $(X_\bullet^n)$ corresponding to $n$ satisfies $X_{k+1}^n=X_k^n$ if $|X_k|\geq n$, and $X_{k+1}^n=X_k+S$ where $S$  is the $\mathbb{Z}$-random variable distributed according to the given (compactly supported)  distribution.

Comment: One simple observation is that if the distribution is supported on $\mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace -1 \rbrace$ then it can't be an example, since there would never be any overshoot in the negative direction yet asymmetric distributions would have some positive overshooting. Similarly, the distribution has to include a positive probability of taking a positive step of size at least $2$.